# Does the Uncharted: Nathan Drake Collection include all the games on the disc?

Tags: ps4, uncharted-series, uncharted-nathan-drake-collection

I was planning to buy the Uncharted: Nathan Drake Collection but I have a slow internet connection. Are Uncharted 1, 2, and 3 already on the disc and can you switch to any of the games like in Borderlands The Handsome Collection, or is only one Uncharted game on the disc and the rest have to be downloaded? And do any of the games require the internet to play?

Answer (score 4):

The Nathan Drake Collection contains the first three Uncharted games within the disk. The only thing that would need to download are any updates and patches.

Playing any of the Uncharted games does not require an internet connection. The Nathan Drake Collection only contains the single-player story and does not support online multi-player. Uncharted 4 does support online multi-player, but it is optional.